# How can I read english.pickle file from nltk module?

Tags: python, nlp, pickle

I am trying to figure out why I cant read the contents of the english.pickle file downloaded from nltk module.

I first downloaded the nltk file using this code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

I then looked for inside the punkt file that I have on my home directory and found english.pickle file. I used the following code to read the file in python:

```
import pickle
with open('english.pickle', 'rb') as file:
    x = pickle.load(file)
```

It all seemed fine, however, when I am running the variable x (which should be storing the pickled data) i am unable to retrieve the data from as I would from any other pickled file.

Instead I am only getting the object name and the id:

```
<nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktParameters at 0x7f86cf6c0cd0>
```

The problem is I need to access the content of the file and I cant iterate through as it is not iterable.

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded the `punkt` tokenizer, for which the documentation says:

> This tokenizer divides a text into a list of sentences by using an
> unsupervised algorithm to build a model for abbreviation words,
> collocations, and words that start sentences.  It must be trained on a
> large collection of plaintext in the target language before it can be
> used.

After this:

```
with open('english.pickle', 'rb') as file:
    x = pickle.load(file)
```

You should have a `nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer` object. You can call methods on that object to perform tokenization.  E.g.:

```
>>> x.tokenize('This is a test. I like apples. The cow is blue.')
['This is a test.', 'I like apples.', 'The cow is blue.']
```